# Text-area with em not working in IE and Opera

Tags: css, textarea, font-size

This is my first attempt to make a complete webpage layout in 'em' measurements. I am building a live preview markdown editor.

This page works perfectly in Firefox and chrome, but in IE(i have IE9) and Opera(updated last night) The text-area shoots the boundary significantly. In Opera, the border of textarea is also not showing rounded corners. ( text area is showing rounded corner but not its border)

This is css for the textarea

```
#pad {
    background-color:#BBBB99;
    background-image:url("../img/edit.png");
    border-color:rgba(32, 32, 52, 0.39);
    border-radius:1em 1em 1em 1em;
    font-size:1.3em;
    height:33.3em;
    margin:0.3em;
    outline:medium none;
    padding:0.9em 0.7em;
    resize:none;
    width:26em;
    text-align: left;

}
```

and this is the html snippet

```
<div class='container'>
  <div id='left'>
    <textarea id = 'pad' wrap="on" ></textarea>
  </div>

  <div id='right'>
    <div id='preview'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have set 'font: 100%' in the body.
[Here is the link of demo if you need to check it.](http://editortest.comule.com/editor_02.php)

Comment: Is one of the challenges of this project to build the page entirely in `em` measurements or are you willing to use `%`? I would personally set the width as a percentage (eg, `90%`) rather than a fixed `em` measurement.

Comment: I will try it in percentages. thanks. I am free to use %, I am trying to learn making fluid layouts in web pages. Earlier i used px in this webpage but the div#right moved down on my friends square moniter. That is when i thought to change my technique.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is caused by the changing of the font-size in `#pad`.

When you set a base font-size, for example 18px, then all the child elements treat `1em` as `18px`. However, if you change the font-size in one of the children to 1.2em then all the child elements nested within that child will start treating `1em` as `22px`:

```
body {
    font-size: 18px;
}

.parent {
    font-size: 1em;   /* 18px */
}

.child {
    font-size: 1.2em  /* 22px */
}

.child > .child {
    font-size: 1em;   /* 22px */
}
```

What I think is happening in Internet Explorer is that the font-size is being changed to `1.2em` before the `width` of `#pad` is calculated. So the width in Firefox and Chrome is `26 * 18px` where as in IE the width is `26 * 22px`.

To get around this, I would set the width as a percentage instead of a fixed `em` measurement.

**Edit**

In regards the the rounded corners issue in Opera; it seems that Opera does not take kindly to the fact that neither the `border-width` nor `border-style` have been set.

Try changing `border-color` to `border: 1px solid rgba(32, 32, 52, 0.39);` and see if that resolves your issue.

Comment: the dom structure is `body-> container(div)-> left(div)-> pad(textarea)`. In Body, i set `font-size: 100%`. there is no font change in the container and in div-left. then i made a font change in the textarea it self. I changed the padding, margin, of div-left and pad to % and set width and height to 95% in pad. Still the same result in opera and IE. When i set the % in a textarea, does it mean it is 95% of the parent div i.e. 95% of div-left?

Comment: Edit for previous comment. It took me some time to realize that opera was taking from cache. so after the changes i mentioned above, (height:95%; width:95%); Width has been adjusted as it should be, but now in all browsers, height is shrunk to default of textarea, which does not grow as i have enabled overflow. I tried using `min-height:95%; max-height:96%` no effect. Now this effect is in all four browsers.

Comment: @AbhinavKulshreshtha You can only use height as a percentage when the parent element has a fixed height. So you can either set the height in `.wysiwym-editor` to `33.3em` or keep the height in `#pad` as an `em` measurement and concede that it will be taller in IE (not really a bad thing as it will still be contained in the parent).

Comment: This worked... thanks. any tip for the corner problem in opera. the textarea and the divs get the curve. the border of div is also rounded. but the border of textarea is pointed in Opera. [Link to snapshot of opera textarea corner](http://editortest.comule.com/img/Capture.PNG). [My website](http://editortest.comule.com/editor_02.php)

Comment: @AbhinavKulshreshtha it seems that Opera isn't happy that there is no `border-width` or `border-style` set. Try changing `border-color` to `border: 1px solid rgba(32, 32, 52, 0.39);` and see if this resolves your issue.

Comment: Yes it solves it. Thank you. This is question is now officially solved.

Answer (score 0):

for special css3 features, use vendor prefixes for each browser :
instead of `border-radius:1em 1em 1em 1em;` use :

```
-webkit-border-radius:1em;
-moz-border-radius:1em;
-o-border-radius:1em;
-ms-border-radius:1em;
border-radius:1em;
```

Comment: Nope. [Browsers have supported](http://caniuse.com/border-radius) the standard property `border-radius` for ages now. There's no need for *any* of the vendor prefixed properties in your answer. More importantly, your answer won't fix the problem described in the question.

Comment: Nop.. still not working. It is strange that the textarea is showing its rounded corner, but its border remains straight in opera. I thought it is always IE which couses the problem

Comment: @thirtydot : what if a user with ff3 visits the site? won't the rounded borders matter for him?

Comment: My Main problem is that the text area is overshooting its expected layout in IE and Opera. check the link.

Comment: Firefox is up to version 13 now. Does it really matter if users with a browser that's *ten major versions* behind the current version don't see rounded corners? I didn't think so. I recommend that you delete this answer, since it's useless and it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @thirtydot thank you for the link in your first comment here. caniuse website is a great help for new learners.