# Padding and line-height not consistent across Mac / PC browsers

Tags: css

I'm seeing some pretty dramatic differences in line-height/padding in [a couple of elements on this page](http://www.utdanacenter.org/wp/pre-kindergarten-12-education/tools-for-teaching-and-learning/academic-youth-development/summer-start-ayd/), specifically the page title (The Charles A Dana Center) and the "Academic Youth Development" header. On Safari/FF on Mac, the text is squeezed right up toward the top of their lines; in all browsers on PC it looks just about evenly vertically spaced.

I have a css-reset and Modernizr running if that matters.

This is the css for the site header:

```
.site-title h1 {
    font-size:2.5em;  
    margin:.1em 0em 0em;
    text-transform: none;  
}
.site-title a {
    display:inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#0363a8;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #82B2D9;
    line-height:1em;
    border: none;   
}
```

And this is the css for the blue-backgrounded page title:

```
.parent-title {
    font-size:2em;
    color: #0D72BA;
    font-family: 'Bree Serif',Georgia,'Times New Roman',serif;
    font-weight:400;
    border: none;
    background-color:#D8E1F1;
    border-radius:8px;
    display:block;
    padding:.2em .5em .2em;
    margin-bottom:.72em;
    line-height:1em;
}
```

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: It is probably down to changing the font-size in the same class as applying padding and line-height as em. See the first part of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11172593/681807) about em behaviour in Chrome and Firefox vs IE

Comment: Thanks @MyHeadHurts! Moving the padding/line-height to separate tags fixed it, I think. If you want to move this comment over to an answer I'll mark it as 'solved' so you can get cred. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad you solved it. My comment was more of a hint so I think it would be more beneficial to users if you add the answer and explain what you did to fix it. I hadn't actually thought of moving the styles into different tags so I think you deserve the credit for that.

Comment: ... and I have to take it back. Not solved in the most recent flavors of Safari & FF on OSX. I'm testing through Browserlab and it looks fine there, but apparently not on newer versions. Sigh. I'll keep playing and will post an answer if I find one. Thanks!

Comment: This question is a possible duplicate of: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11726442/font-rendering-line-height-issue-on-mac-pc-outside-of-element]